# Avoid JS variable renaming in HTML files on ParcelJS

Tags: javascript, html, minify, parceljs

I am using ParcelJS as a module bundler and for some reasons I am using JS variables in the HTML which are later to be read by JS code.

In my HTML:

```
<script>
  var myVar = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
  };
</script>
```

In my JS:

```
console.log(window.myVar.key1);
```

When I build the static site with `parcel build`, the JS variable in the HTML gets renamed, so I can't read it from the JS file anymore:

```
<script>var a = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' };</script>
```

According to [the Parcel docs](https://parceljs.org/html.html), it looks like the renaming (mangling) is done by [htmlnano](https://github.com/posthtml/htmlnano), which uses [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) under the hood for the JS minification.

I've tried using a `.htmlnanorc` file with the following contents:

```
{
  "minifyJs": {
    "mangle": false
  },
  "removeComments": false
}
```

I've only added the `removeComments` option just to make sure the `.htmlnanorc` file is being processed. HTML comments are kept, so it is.

But the JS variable keeps getting renamed, even though I've tried several Terser configurations according to their docs. So it looks like htmlnano is ignoring any configs under the `minifyJs` key.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Or could it be some kind of ParcelJS or htmlnano bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your variable names to

```
<script>
  window.myVar = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
  };
</script>
```

There's no option to change this behavior using `parcel.js`, so you have to go through a workaround.

<sup>[Source](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3934)</sup>

Comment: This is an acceptable solution in my environment and it seems to work, so thank you for your answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. However, it seems disappointing that ParcelJS does not actually support custom Terser configurations for the htmlnano minifyJs options, I'd say they ought to fix it :)

Comment: I do agree that it's frustrating when we're looking to do something using a certain plugin and we're not able to find that functionality by default. But well, we have to work with what we have :)

Comment: This helped implementing MTCaptcha https://www.mtcaptcha.com/. Thanks.